# Regular expression to search contents that contain qr in it?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

```
grep -rlw . -e '%QR%'
```

I am doing something like this.  Anything could be before QR and anything could be after QR. It could be nothing as well.

I am searching for file names containing QR inside in content(not in name) in them.

Any idea on how I could incorporate this into search. In SQL, I'd do something like I mentioned above by adding % at the beginning and last.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep 'something' file(s)
  # look for lines containing the substring "something" 
  # in the file (or all files). 
  # note: if several files it will add "filename:" in front of each lines, but does not look in those filenames

some program | grep 'something'
 # look for lines of output of "some program" 
 #  containing the substring 'something'
```

So if you need to look for filenames containing "QR" with grep, you could:

```
ls | grep "QR"  # or ls -R | grep QR
```

But it's better to not parse ls (many pitfalls, for exemple if the file contains a newline, or spaces) : use `find` instead ?

```
find /some/path -type f -name '*QR*' 
-or-
find /some/path -type f -name '*QR*' -ls
 # to get the long output, showing infos on each files found.
 # note: this exemple only matches regular files, not symlinks nor pipe nor directories
```

If you look for the name of files mentionning "QR" you can:

```
grep -r -l "QR" /some/path
  # l = lowercase L = list filenames matching
  # r = recursively from /some/path or ./relative_path
```

Comment: I'm searching for content, not filename.

Comment: "_if you need to look for filenames containing "QR"_" - just use `*QR*` and avoid the `ls | grep` mess

Comment: @roaima Doesn't work.

Comment: @achhainsan : your question states: `I am searching for file names containing QR in them` : in them = in the file names.
If you meant 'I am looking for the names of files containing mentions of QR', then it's the first mode :  for exemple: `grep -lr "QR" ./` # look recursively ffrom the ./ path (or another one), and just mention the filenames matching

Comment: (my answer is deliberately simple and shows basics, even though @achhainsan seems to already know them, to be helpful to others)

Comment: Suggesting `ls | grep pattern` instead of `ls pattern` is not helpful though. It is fragile and needlessly complicated. Let's not show anti-patterns.

Comment: @achhainsan "_doesn't work_" - please be more descriptive. You don't give any detail for someone to try a different approach. Based on your description this does work exactly as required. Therefore there is a disjoint between what you've written and what I've read. I can't fill that because all I know is my solution "_doesn't work_". You asked the question so you need to fill in more detail

Comment: @roaima can you share the full command? what I thought was full command didn't work.

Comment: No problem, @achhainsan. What do you want to do with the files that you find?

Comment: My objective is to just find those files and read them.

Comment: @achhainsan, "_and read them_" - with `cat`? With `less`?

Comment: anything is alright, cat , less vi etc. No specific purpose. Just need to read them.

Comment: @achhainsan in that case simply `cat *QR*` or `less *QR*`. Let the shell worry about finding the files, and you worry about what to do with them once it's found them for you